# Project with object detection on raspberry pi (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am doing a research project that consists in an object detection AI, capable of detecting by a webcam 7 classes of objects.

Using google colab, I successfully trained the ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco model, using tensorflow 1.15.

The objective is to run the model in a Raspberry Pi 3b+, using the official camera and Google Coral EdgeTPU device, so the model must be quantized in order to use it.

The issue comes with the testing part; so after training the model, converted it to tflite using:

```
!python export_tflite_ssd_graph.py --pipeline_config_path="/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Data/models/research/object_detection/training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco.config" --trained_checkpoint_prefix=training/model.ckpt-28523 --output_directory=compiler/ --add_postprocessing_op=true
```

and

```
!tflite_convert --graph_def_file=compiler/tflite_graph.pb --output_file=compiler/detect.tflite --output_format=TFLITE --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --mean_values=128 --std_dev_values=128 --change_concat_input_ranges=false --allow_custom_ops
```

Converted model: https://gofile.io/d/kOe2Ac
Tried to test the model using Edje Electronics webcam script. *[found here](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/TFLite_detection_webcam.py)*

And outputs this error:

`RuntimeError: tensorflow/lite/kernels/detection_postprocess.cc:404 ValidateBoxes(decoded_boxes, num_boxes) was not true.Node number 98 (TFLite_Detection_PostProcess) failed to invoke.`

The weirdest thing is that if I try to run the same script in my current workstation (with tensorflow 1.15.1), the code runs flawlessly, so there should be something wrong with the rpi.

The rpi is running tensorflow 1.15.2, built from the WHL source. Actually y tried with all the versions that I can, but always the same error.

I will be so grateful with any help that could bring to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried already prepared quantized models from zoo to run on your RPi configuration to make sure SW/HW are fine?

Comment: yes, already tried with coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1.0_quant_2018_06_29 from googleapis...works flawlessly. So I do still not understand why this weird behaviour. If my model will not be correctly trained or compiled, it will not be working on the workstation, and it works perfectly...maybe it's something related with tensorflow lite on the rpi?

Comment: Is it possible to test your model on RPi without TPU?

Comment: yes, and also the same error happens

Comment: May you please share tflite model or screen shot of its bottom part, as seen in Netron? Also  what is "node number 98" can come handy. It can be found in netron as well. I think something wrong with decoder: they have custom op for decoder processor, it can be incompatible with your changes.

Comment: Of course, here it is the tflite: https://gofile.io/d/kOe2Ac.

Comment: I have found similar issues around tensorflow github. While I cant provide you a solution you still can take a look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35419#issuecomment-635991240) and maybe [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7918#issuecomment-625123318)

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried all of them except on the first one, the last comment from ipetel, who says that he resolved the issue on one tensorflow library...Unfortunately I don't know how to do that, so maybe you can help me mate.

Comment: He edited TF source code and build his own version. I have built TF locally as well as different binaries like tflite interpreters. Once setup is made you can build anything from repo. Instructions are straight forward and you will not use much time to make it work.

Comment: Hi mate, I created a github thread and here is what happens to me right now... https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45630. If I change the model to mobilenet v2 to v1, it runs flawlessly, but unfortunately the error still happens if I run the model compiled and quantized for coral Edge TPU. Do you know why? And how can I make it work with the tpu?

Answer (score 0):

`ValidateBoxes` verifies if the the [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1ce28a3f8a7670eda543176c7fe3a78b5db11a1e/tensorflow/lite/kernels/detection_postprocess.cc#L387-L389) of the detected box makes sense or not. And the issue is usually caused by detected boxes with the same xmin/xmax or ymin/ymax, which should not be flagged as an issue, and the rest of the code and tolerant with the case very well. The issue has been fixed in TFLite and it is now available through the tf-nightly build.

If you'd like to build TF from source, here is a [workaround solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7918#issuecomment-696805292).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the info! But how is that it works flawlessly on other pc and not on the rpi? Do i need to install tf-nightly instead of tensorflow? This might be of the cpu architecture?